# Does ambient radiation cause air to emit light?

Tags: ions

In a cloud chamber, atoms of air are ionized by passing radiation, providing nucleation sites that enable droplets to form. When those atoms are de-excited, one would expect them to release light; does this happen, and if so is this radiation detectable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes de-exciting air molecules produce light.  This happens most beautifully in the [polar aurora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora#Colors_and_wavelengths_of_auroral_light). In the lower atmosphere (where people live and build cloud chambers), this [ionized-air glow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionized-air_glow) will be dominated by nitrogen de-excitations that produce blue-violet and (mostly) UV photons.

You need, unfortunately, a lot of ionization to produce enough light to see easily by eye, since [only about 17 photons](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/1365249) are produced per MeV of ionization energy in air.  This means that a typical alpha particle in air will produce $\lesssim 10^2$ photons, and most of those will be in the UV. It  has been shown that the human eye under ideal conditions can (dimly) detect the flash of light [produced by about 30 visible photons entering the eye](https://research.physics.illinois.edu/QI/Photonics/pdf/PWDec16Holmes.pdf), so the flash from the handful of visible photons produced by an alpha particle in air should be too dim to see.

Nevertheless, check out the [Pierre Auger observatory](https://www.auger.org/) to see how detecting this [UV glow](https://www.auger.org/outreach/cosmic-rays/detection) from cosmic ray air showers can be used to do great astrophysics.